# Color property in CALayer subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is driving me nuts. I'm trying to change a custom property "mycolor" of a CALayer subclass, this is my code:

```
#import "Circle"

@interface Circle()
   @property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor * mycolor;
   @property (nonatomic) float initial_angle;
   @property (nonatomic) float end_angle;
@end

@implementation Circle

@synthesize mycolor;
@synthesize initial_angle, end_angle;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        CGFloat red =  (CGFloat)random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
        CGFloat blue = (CGFloat)random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
        CGFloat green = (CGFloat)random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
        self.mycolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
        self.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    }
    return self;
}


-(void) changeColor {
    CGFloat red =  (CGFloat)random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat blue = (CGFloat)random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat green = (CGFloat)random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
    self.mycolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
}

- (void) animate {
    float final = arc4random() % 360;
    float afrom = self.initial_angle;
    self.initial_angle = final;
    CABasicAnimation * anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"initial_angle"];
    anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:afrom];
    anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:final];
    anim.duration = 5;
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [self addAnimation:anim forKey:@"initial_angle"];

    final = arc4random() % 360;
    afrom = self.end_angle;
    self.end_angle = final;
    anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"end_angle"];
    anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:afrom];
    anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:final];
    anim.duration = 5;
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [self addAnimation:anim forKey:@"end_angle"];    

}

- (void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 50, 50);
    CGContextAddArc(ctx, 50, 50, 50, initial_angle*M_PI/180, end_angle*M_PI/180, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.mycolor);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.mycolor.CGColor);   
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

}

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString*)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"initial_angle"]||
        [key isEqualToString:@"end_angle"]||
        [key isEqualToString:@"mycolor"]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
    }
}

@end
```

changeColor and animate are public methods. Animate gets called every second and changeColor every time the user taps de circle.

Everything works fine except that in "drawInContext" mycolor is always null. Don't know why.

Comment: How are you creating instances of `Circle`?

Comment: I believe you should subclass the + layer method, not the init for a CALayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried logging the value of mycolor immediately after you set it?

Your code looks sound, so there's definitely something weird going on. Is it possible you've created a custom setter or getter method for mycolor somewhere and not implemented it properly?

I assume you're using ARC - have you tried setting the mycolor ivar directly instead of via the setter? (in ARC that should be fine - it won't leak or get released unexpectedly)

Comment: If I log mycolor after I set it, it is ok. It only fails in drawInContext.

But I just found out it isn't always null. There's a frame, when the animation ends and before it begins again, that the circle blinks for a millisecond with the color and it logs the color ok.

So my guess is it has something to do with me trying to set the color to the model Layer instead of the presentation layer, that's the one being animated... ??

Comment: Have you considered using a CAShapeLayer instead of this approach? If you're trying to draw an animated polygon filled with a color using CALayers, I think CAShapeLayer has pretty much done all the work for your already.

Comment: You mean subclassing CAShapeLayer?

Comment: Yes, or just adding it as a sublayer of your Circle Layer and using it directly.

Comment: CAShapeLayers have similar methods and capabilities for path drawing to Core Graphics, but they already support animating the fill and stroke colors out of the box, and the performance is significantly better than drawing with Core Graphics (I think they draw the path using OpenGL).

Comment: Thankyou, that seems to work. Now I'm finding other problems which make me think if this is the right way all together...

Answer (score 0):

```
@synthesize mycolor = _mycolor;
_mycolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
```

try use _mycolor in init method and drawInContext.

```
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.mycolor.CGColor);
```

I think in drawInContext you could just use the instance variable instead of the property.

Answer (score 0):

The correct initializer for a `CALayer` is `+layer`, you should override the `+layer` method instead of the `-init` that is maybe not even called at all.