# Non-animatable properties in subclasses of CALAyer

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-animation

I have defined a subclass of `CALayer` with an animatable property as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197239/animated-cashapelayer-pie/9150991#9150991). I would now like to add another (non-animatable) property to that layer to support its internal bookkeeping.

I set the value of the new property in `drawInContext:` but what I find that it is always reset to 0 when the next call is made. Is this so because Core Animation assumes that this property is also for animation, and that it "animates" its value at constant 0 lacking further instructions? In any case, how can I add truly non-animatable properties to subclasses of `CALayer`?

I have found a preliminary workaround, which is using a global `CGFloat _property` instead of `@property (assign) CGFloat property` but would prefer to use normal property syntax.

**UPDATE 1**

This is how I try to define the property in `MyLayer.m`:

```
@interface MyLayer()

@property (assign) CGFloat property;

@end
```

And this is how I assign a value to it at the end of `drawInContext:`:

```
self.property = nonZero;
```

The property is e.g. read at the start of `drawInContext:` like so:

```
NSLog(@"property=%f", self.property);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Maybe this it was causes the problem (code inherited from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197239/animated-cashapelayer-pie/9150991#9150991) sample)?

```
- (id)actionForKey:(NSString *) aKey {
    if ([aKey isEqualToString:@"someAnimatableProperty"]) {
       CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:aKey];
       animation.fromValue = [self.presentationLayer valueForKey:aKey];
       return animation;
    }
    return [super actionForKey:aKey]; // also applies to my "property"
}
```

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116203/color-property-in-calayer-subclass)

Comment: Can you show how the property is defined and how its values are set and where they are read?

Comment: Are you trying to read the value during an animation?

Comment: What are you doing in `-initWithLayer:`?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I guess the answer is yes, since I'm reading it in `drawInContext:`.

Comment: `MyLayer` does not override `CALayer`´s `initWithLayer:` (yet). Should it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56842/discussion-between-david-ronnqvist-and-drux).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To access your standard property from within the drawing method, during an animation, you need to make a few modifications.

### Implement initializer

When CoreAnimation performs your animation, *it creates shadow copies of your layer*, and each copy will be rendered in a different frame. To create such copies, it calls `-initWithLayer:`.
From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> If you are implementing a custom layer subclass, you can override this method and use it to copy the values of instance variables into the new object. Subclasses should always invoke the superclass implementation.

Therefore, you need to implement `-initWithLayer:` and use it to copy manually the value of your property on the new instance, like this:

```
- (id)initWithLayer:(id)layer
{
    if ((self = [super initWithLayer:layer])) {
        // Check if it's the right class before casting
        if ([layer isKindOfClass:[MyCustomLayer class]]) {
            // Copy the value of "myProperty" over from the other layer
            self.myProperty = ((MyCustomLayer *)layer).myProperty;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

### Access properties through model layer

The copy, anyway, *takes place before the animation starts*: you can see this by adding a `NSLog` call to `-initWithLayer:`. So as far as CoreAnimation knows, your property will always be zero. Moreover, the copies it creates are *readonly*, if you try to set `self.myProperty` from within `-drawInContext:`, when the method is called on one of the presentation copies, you get an exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerReadOnly', reason:  
    'attempting to modify read-only layer <MyLayer: 0x8e94010>' ***
```

Instead of setting `self.myProperty`, you should write

```
self.modelLayer.myProperty = 42.0f
```

as `modelLayer` will instead refer *to the original `MyCustomLayer` instance*, and all the presentation copies share the same model. Note that you must do this *also when you read the variable*, not only when you set it. For completeness, one should mention as well the property `presentationLayer`, that instead returns the current (copy of the) layer being displayed.